# Prevent vmware workstion update

Tags: updates, vmware, vmware-workstation

Some Ubuntu systems have limited access, sometimes VMWare workstation gives a message to allow the installation of updates, because they do not have access to install the program, enter the root password.

The first solution

```
 preference - tab update.
 Disable the following items.

 check for product updates on startup
 check for software components as needed
```

The second solution

https://itsfoss.com/prevent-package-update-ubuntu/

The third solution

```
1.uninstall the vmware workstation.
2. search all the file and directory with "vmware" keyword and delete them.
3. reboot
4. install vmware workstation.
5.  modify /etc/vmware/config.ini
installerDefaults.autoSoftwareUpdateEnabled = "no "
installerDefaults.componentDownloadEnabled  = "no"
```

Unfortunately, none of them solved the problem and after the update, the version of VMWare workstation does not change either.